# NPV of two annuities

Tags: annuity

For exam preparation we are given some past papers, however there are no solutions and I would like to know if my logic is correct for the following question:

> Assume you are 25 years old. An insurance company is offering you the
>   following retirement contract: Pay in \$2000 per year for the next 40
>   years. When you reach 65 years of age, you will receive \$20000 per
>   year until you reach 100. Assume the prevailing interest rate is 5%
>   per year, all payments occur at year end, and it is January 1 now. Is
>   this annuity a good deal?

Comment: Please Type your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that "I" was born on 1st of January. I pay for $40$ years and receive payments for $36$ years ($65$ to $100$). So I pay when I am 
$$25, 26 \dots 64$$
and receive payments when I am
$$65, 66,\dots 100.$$
Hence the PVs of the annuities are:

$\begin{equation}
PV_{paid} = \frac{2000}{0.05}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{40}\right) = 34318.1727 \quad \text{(to 4dp)}\\
PV_{received~when~65} = \frac{20000}{0.05}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{36}\right) = 330937.0342\quad \text{(to 4dp)}\\
PV_{received} = PV_{received~when~65}\times\left(\frac{1}{1.05}\right)^{40} = 47008.1768\quad \text{(to 4dp)}\\
\end{equation}
$

$$\therefore NPV = PV_{received} - PV_{paid} = 12690.0041 \quad \text{(to 4dp)}.
$$
Hence the annuity is a good deal (having positive NPV).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in your class and was stuck on this too

Here's how I make it:

PV of contributions = (2000/0.05)*[1-(1/1.05^40)] = 34318.17

PV of amount received = (20000/0.05)*[1-(1/1.05^35)] = 327483.89

Value today of amount received = PV of amount received / (1.05)^40 = 59369.64

Therefore this annuity is a good deal. Still unsure with this, have you come to a conclusion yet? Thanks

Comment: Why would you discount the "PV of amount received" by (1.05)^35 instead of $1.05^{40}$? I believe that you calculate that annuities PV for when "I am 64", which is 40 years from now.

Comment: Yeah got you! It should read 40. In which case the amount is 46517.67

Comment: Additionally from 65 to 100 there are 36 years, as it is inclusive counting.

Comment: You should be receiving payments until the end of your 99th, ie a total of 35 payments as you don't receive anything at the end of the year in which you turn 100. So you receive 65, 66, ..., 99.Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: We could argue about it, however I think the question itself was phrased very vaguely... I think if you state your assumptions that by the 100th year you won't receive any money that's fine. I assumed that until 100 means until 100 inclusive.